# Automatic authentication in rcirc

Tags: irc, rcirc

I'm trying to achieve the automatic authentication of my registered nickname on Freenode, so that I can join the `#emacs` IRC channel.

Since I upload my Emacs config to a public repository, I've opted to grab the personal data of my nickname and password from a file on my local machine.

Below is the code I've come up with trying to achieve this. And I don't know why it's not working.

It seems like a trivial task to accomplish, but I'm at a loss; not knowing if it's a problem with the syntax, semantics, and/or the way the package handles my nickname/password.

```el
(defun jd:get-string-from-file (filePath beg end)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filePath nil beg end)
    (buffer-string)))

(defvar jd:irc-nickname (jd:get-string-from-file "~/.authinfo" 0 15))
(defvar jd:irc-password (jd:get-string-from-file "~/.authinfo" 16 26))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; `rcirc.el'
(setq rcirc-default-nick jd:irc-nickname)
(setq rcirc-authinfo '(("freenode" nickserv jd:irc-nickname jd:irc-password)))
(setq rcirc-server-alist '(("irc.freenode.net" :port 6667 :channels ("#emacs"))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (that I see) is this line:

```el
(setq rcirc-authinfo '(("freenode" nickserv jd:irc-nickname jd:irc-password)))
```

If you `C-h v rcirc-authinfo`, the value will be `("freenode" nickserv jd:irc-nickname jd:irc-password)`. I'm not sure if `rcirc` accepts symbols for nickname and password, but I bet not.

The problem is, the quote `'` quotes everything, including `jd:irc-nickname` and `jd:irc-password`, so they are left unevaluated.

What you want to do is use backquote `, which enables you to evaluate seleced elements:

```el
(setq rcirc-authinfo `(("freenode" nickserv ,jd:irc-nickname ,jd:irc-password)))
```

Example:

```el
(setq mynick "pony")
"pony"

(setq mypass "password")
"password"

'(mynick mypass)
(mynick mypass)

`(,mynick ,mypass)
("pony" "password")
```

Relevant manual node: [`(elisp) Backquote`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).